# Scaling an image from the iPhone - iOS App

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimage

I let the user select a photo from the iPhone library, and I grab the UIImage.

I output the size of the image, and it says 320x480, but it doesn't seem to be, because when I draw the image on the screen using CGRectMake(0,0,320,480), it only shows the upper left portion of the image. Aren't the images much bigger than 320x480 because of the high resolution?

I'd like to scale the image to force it to be 320x480. If it is less than 320x480, it should not be rescaled at all. If the width is greater than 320 or the height is greater than 480, it should scale in a way so that it becomes as close to 320x480 as possible, but by keeping the proper proportion of width to height. So, for instance, if it scales to 320x420, that is fine, or 280x480.

How can I do this in Objective-C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the image view's content mode like this:

```
myView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

will preserve the aspect ratio.

Comment: but when I pick the image using UIImagePickerViewController, it comes up with this white square and the user can move the image around but it only captures the portion in the white square

Comment: What does your container hierarchy look like?  Are all those frames set up correctly?

Comment: I have a UIViewcontroller and then I present the UIImagePickerController